# Simple sed replacement of tabs mysteriously failing

Tags: sed, osx, regular-expression

This ought to be really simple, but for some reason it is not working:

```
sed -i.bak -E 's/\t/  /' file.txt
```

Instead of replacing tab characters, it's replacing `t` characters.  I've tried every variation on this I could think of, playing with quoting, etc. I've Googled and found [everyone else](http://mlawire.blogspot.com/2009/07/convert-tabs-to-spaces.html) using pretty similar expressions and they seem to work for them.

The `-E` is an OS X thing.  I thought the failure might be a result of some weird quirk of OS X's `sed`, so I tried it with Ruby as well (without the `-i`), and got the same result:

```
ruby -pe '$_.gsub!(/\t/,"  ")' < file.txt > file.new
```

I'm using Bash 3.2.51 on OS X, and iTerm, although I can't see how any of those could be terribly relevant.  I haven't set any weird environment variables, though I can post any that you think might be relevant.

What could be wrong?

***UPDATE***:  I must have made some other mistake or typo when I tried the Ruby version, since Gilles points out that it *does* work (and I've *never* had him steer me wrong!).  I'm not sure what happened, but I'm pretty sure it must have been my mistake.

Comment: May be you should try to replace the `\t` in the `sed` statement with `CTRL-V<TAB>` where `<TAB>` is the tab key and `CTRL-V` is control key and `v` pressed together.

Comment: if ruby is also getting wrong answer, then it could be your regexp library. (I have tested both your commands, and both replace tab with 2 spaces.) It so then hopefully if you install Gnu sed it will also install the correct library.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The syntax `\t` for a tab character in sed is not standard. That escape is a [GNU sed extension](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed//manual/html_node/Escapes.html). You find a lot of examples online that use it because a lot of people use GNU sed (it's the sed implementation on non-embedded Linux). But [OS X sed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html), like other *BSD sed, doesn't support `\t` for tab and instead treats `\t` as meaning backslash followed by `t`.

There are many solutions, such as:

- Use a literal tab character.

  ```
  sed -i.bak 's/  /  /' file.txt
  ```
- Use `tr` or `printf` to produce a tab character.

  ```
  sed -i.bak "s/$(printf '\t')/  /" file.txt
  sed -i.bak "s/$(echo a | tr 'a' '\t')/  /" file.txt
  ```
- Use bash's [string syntax allowing backslash escapes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting).

  ```
  sed -i.bak $'s/\t/  /' file.txt
  ```
- Use Perl, Python or Ruby. The Ruby snippet that you posted does work.

Comment: For sed scripts which are contained in a `...sed` script (used via `-f` option), the literal tab characters seem the only possibility to me. When editing this with vim, `set noexpandtab` is important.

Comment: **Warning:** Only use that "literal tab character" technique if you want your coworker to come back behind you and break your script later. Only use that `tr` technique if you want your coworker to stab you in the face when they read your script.

Comment: Is the second double-quotation mark misplaced in the second block of code? I had to move it to where the closing single-quote currently is.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the bash string syntax... I had no idea (and this is the best option, IMHO).

Comment: `sed $'s/<regex>/\t/' file.txt` works for inserting, but the `$` seems to break my script when I try to include part of the regex in my substitution, i.e. `sed $'s,\(ontology/[0-9]\+\),\t\txxx\1xxx\t\t,'` gives `         xxxxxx         ` with my expected match value replaced by ``. Is there a there an equivalent to `\1` when using bash's string syntax? Edit: there is supposed to the the U+231C unicode character in the middle of the xxx<U+231C>xxx.

Comment: @Josh Double the backslash: if you write `sed $'…\\…'`, sed sees `…\…`

Comment: Gotcha, like `sub` or `gsub` in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Use a Bash specific [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Types_of_quoting) which lets you use strings like in C, so that a real tab character is passed to sed, not an escape sequence:

```
sed -i.bak -E $'s/\t/  /' file.txt
```

Comment: Also called "ANSI-C" quoting if others want to look up more info about it.

Comment: Seems to work on any bourne shell, works on non-bash UNIXes as well. Doesn't work on csh-variants though.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -i $'s/\t/  /g' file.txt
```

works for me on OS X and is the same command i use on linux all the time.

Comment: Note that this replaces all tabs on every row whereas the OP intends to only replace the first (judging from the command they use).

Answer (score 2):

As noted, not all `sed` implementations support the notation of `\t` as a horizontal tab.

You can easily achieve your substitution with:

```
 perl -pi.old -e 's{\t+}{ }g' file.txt
```

This performs an in situ replacment which preserves your original file as "*.old".  Perl allows alternate delimiters for the classic `/` making the expression much more readable (i.e. devoid of the "leaning toothpick" syndrome).

The `+` says one or more repetitions of a tab character are to be replaced.  The `g` modifier enables global replacements throughout the end of each line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more powerful `sed` (supporting `\t` and more) than the one on OS X, install [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/).

Comment: Since it didn't work with Ruby either, I'm not sure why I would conclude that OS X's `sed` is the problem.  Do you have a reason to believe that's the problem?  I'd be happy to install GNU sed if I had reason to believe it would solve the problem, but it seems like I've pretty much ruled that out.

Comment: With Ruby, you'll have to use only one backslash: `ruby -pe '$_.gsub!(/\t/,"  ")' < file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `echo` inside `sed`:

`sed -i "s/$(echo '\t')//g"`

Comment: Note that `echo '\t'` will just output `\t` in some shells' implementation of `echo`.

Comment: You'll need the `-e` option: `echo -e '\t'`

Answer (score 0):

If it is okay to require `bash` or `zsh` as a shell, then this is the easiest solution I can think of:

```
sed "s/$(echo -n -e "\t")/ /" file.txt
```

Note however, that `echo` flags (`-n` and `-e`) are undefined in POSIX, so a POSIX conform shell doesn't require to understand theses flags, yet many will for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing from the above answers, here is a simple copy-and-pasteable version that works on OS X and you don't have to think about.

```
mysql -h myhost.com -u username -p  -e "select * from users;" -B --raw  | sed $'s/\t/,/g' > filename.csv
```

The $ in the sed command is the magic that makes it work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm surprised no one suggested the very simple solution of:
    `sed -i.bak -E 's/\\\t/  /' file.txt`
That should do the trick.

You need to escape the escape (hence the 3 \s) to allow sed to understand that you are trying to use a \t character in the regular expression when everything is substituted...

Comment: Why three backslashes specifically?

Comment: If I use GNU `sed`, one `\ ` is enough, as no escaping is necessary.  The problem is that BSD `sed` does not support this syntax for tabs.

Comment: Does not work on my El Capitan.

Comment: Gives me literally \t on Mojave

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me.

sed -e 's/[\t]/    /g'

Comment: This is because you use GNU `sed`. This is not what the OP uses.