# Replacing multiple patterns, one of which has brackets, the other a tab character

Tags: sed

I have a text file containing the line:

```
[...]
GFX Clocks and Power:
    800 MHz (MCLK)
    26 MHz (SCLK)
[...]
```

I want to extract the `800 MHz` part of it (the value is not constant) so I want to remove `\t` and `(MCLK)` using `sed`.

This is the command I have now:

```
$ cat ~/test.txt | grep "(MCLK)" | xargs -0 sed -i -e $'s/\t//g' -e 's/\(MCLK\)//g'
```

When run, it returns:

```
sed: can't read     800 MHz (MCLK)
: No such file or directory
```

It doesn't seem to be a newline error and the issue regarding `\t` being a non standard character for `sed` (cf. [Simple sed replacement of tabs mysteriously failing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145299/230119)) should be fixed.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you want to extract that or edit the original file ?

Comment: You don't need `xargs` here. You are processing a single file, not a file with filenames of many files. Also the first `cat` is "unnecessary cat".

Comment: The file doesn't only have this line. I'll edit the question.

Comment: can u share the expected output? u still need only `800 MHz`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `pgrep`:

```
grep -Po '[0-9]+ [KMGT]?Hz(?= \(MCLK\))' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like can help:

```
awk '/(MCLK)/ {print $1,$2}' input_file
```

Comment: `print $1,$2` is doing the job.

Comment: Gives `MHz (MCLK)` for `gawk` with both tab or spaces, need to explicitly add `\t` as  field separator.

Comment: @RoVo, strange, I get it as you said. WIll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sed '/(MCLK)/ s/(MCLK)//g;s/\t//' test.txt
800 MHz
```

- `/(MCLK)/` will search for the keyword.
- `s/(MCLK)//g` will removes `(MCLK)`.
- `s/\t//` will removes tab.

you can use `-i` option to do inline edit.

**For your edited question,**

```
awk -F '[$\t ]' '/(MCLK)/ {print $2" "$3}' test.txt
800 MHz
```

Comment: `tab` and space by default are delimiters for `awk`

Comment: @RomeoNinov it will take anyone, not both concurrently....

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` takes its input and turns it into arguments of the given command. `grep` returns the line you're interested in and `xargs` adds this line as an argument to the `sed` command which expects a file name instead. You don't need `xargs` at all.

You can tell `sed` to only act on a line that matches a pattern:

```
sed -i~ -e '/(MCLK)/{s/\t//g' -e 's/(MCLK)//g}' ~/test.txt
```

Comment: As checked it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Tried with below command and it worked fine too

command

```
sed -n '/MCLK/p' filename| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"| sed -r "s/\(MCLK\)//g"
```

output

```
sed -n '/MCLK/p' filename| sed -r "s/^\s+//g"| sed -r "s/\(MCLK\)//g"

800 MHz
```